# How to Create MongoDB Collection from Json File Using Node

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, schema

i wish to create a mongodb collection from json string with a particular structure. no error messages. mongodb connection works. mongo collection gets created with default data (eg _id/ObjectId) but without content from json file. smth's wrong: how the model is defined and how the update method is defined.

**Input.json**

```
{
  "BYOB" : {
    "abc" : 1
    "def" : "c"
  },
  ...
}
```

**Model.js**

```
...
var modelSchema = new Schema({
  xyz: {
    abc: Number,
    def: String
  }
}
...
```

**Update.js**

```
...
const incoming = require('./Input.json');
var collectionModel = require('./Model');

module.exports.updateModel = function() {
  
    collectionModel.update(
      {},
      incoming,
      {upsert: true, multi: true}, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Collection is created: ", result);
        } else {
          console.log("Collection is not created: ", err);
        }
      }
    );
}
...
```

Comment: To add data from a JSON file into a collection you need to read data from the file and insert. Collection's `insertMany` method can be used to add JSON strings or JS objects. Use `mongoimport` command line utility to import data from JSON file into a collection in an efficient manner.